# Support of a section is closed.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I think I got an conundrum that I put myself with the wrong image of etale sheaf. I have finished the problem by Hartshorne's version but when I transfer this problem to the statement of etale sheaf, I got a completely different statement. This two statement should be completely equivalent due to that etale sheafification is an isomorphism on sheaf category as a subcategory of presheaf category to etale sheaf category.

This is related to Hartshorne 2.1.14 and 2.1.13.

Let $F$ be a sheaf over $X$. Let $U\subset X$ open and $s\in F(U)$. Equivalently, I could think $s$ as a continuous section from $U\to F|_U$ where $F|_U$ is the etale sheaf restricted to $U$. So locally it should be pictorially like a vector bundle but with fiber discrete topology. I want to show $Supp(s)$ is closed. However my argument shows that $Supp(s)$ is also open.

If $s|_p=0$, then clearly, I have a continuous section locally agree with $0$ section locally on an open set. In particular, from continuity of continuous section $s$ on etale, $s(\varinjlim_ix_i)=\varinjlim_i(s(x_i))$. If I have a sequence of points $x_i$ converging to $p$ and their $s(x_i)=0$, then I must have $s(p)=0$ by continuity.

Thus any section not vanishing on $p$ must not-vanishing locally in some open set around $p$. So for any $p\in Supp(s)$, I found a small open set on which it does not vanish. So I conclude $Supp(s)$ is open? If this is the case, then I have $X$ disconnected. There is no reason to expect this.

The closedness can be shown as the following. $Supp(s)^c$ is open as I can find a small section vanishing locally containing each point of $Supp(s)^c$.

Q1. Which part have I done wrong in showing openness of $Supp(s)$? I hope someone could point out whether my image of etale sheaf is correct.

Q2. How should I properly visualize etale sheaf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, do not use (in the present context) the notation $s\vert_p$.
If you want to consider a sheaf $\mathcal F$ as an étalé space, then a section of that sheaf over the open subset $U\subset X$ is a continuous map $U\to \mathcal F$ which composed with the projection $p:\mathcal F\to X$ yields the inclusion map $p\circ s:U\hookrightarrow X$.
It thus makes sense to use the notation $s(p)\in \mathcal F$, in conformity with the general set-theoretic notion of "value of  a function at a point".
It is then perfectly clear that the support of $s$ is closed since its complement $Supp(s)^c$ is open: if $s(p)=0$, then  $s(q)$ will be zero too for all $q$ in a neighbourhood $U(p)$ of $p$.

However the support of $s$ has no reason to be open:
For example if $\mathcal  C$ is the sheaf of continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$, the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\gt 0$ has support $[0, \infty )$ when seen as a section of the sheaf $\mathcal C$, and the good news is that this coincides with the support of $f$ as defined in elementary calculus.

Comment: Is this definition of support pure coincidence with differential geometry or intentional? In differential geometry, one needs to take closure. This makes support apparently closed. It is not apparent that the support is closed in this setting. Why philosophically speaking, it is the natural choice of definition of support by germs not vanishing at the support?

Comment: Strangely things are clearer if you think of the cosupport, i.e. the complement of the support. The cosupport is the biggest **open** subset on which  the function or section  is zero **in both points of view: differential geometric or sheaf theoretic**.  In other words, you have to take the interior of the zero set of your function or section  However in the sheaf case the zero set of a section is already open, so you don't have to take its interior.